# How to put photos (PHAsset) in an iPhone to Dropbox?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, assets, dropbox-api

I am trying to put my photos in my iPhone with Dropbox API, but when I use this code :

```
                mimeType = @".png";
            [[PHImageManager defaultManager]requestImageForAsset:lastAsset targetSize:size contentMode:PHImageContentModeAspectFit options:options resultHandler:^(UIImage* result, NSDictionary* info){

                fileName = [lastAsset.creationDate.description substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, lastAsset.creationDate.description.length-6)];
                data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView.image);
                NSString* imagePath = [[info objectForKey:@"PHImageFileURLKey"]absoluteString];
                NSString* fImagePath = [imagePath substringFromIndex:7];

                [dbRestClient uploadFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",fileName,mimeType] toPath:@"/" withParentRev:nil fromPath:fImagePath];
            }];
```

I have an error which it tells to me "files does not exist : /var/mobile/Media/DCIM/101APPLE/IMG_1080.PNG"

I don't understand why ?!
What is the correct path to retrieve and store my videos in Dropbox ?

Comment: Yes, but my code works well with the Simulator, and it doesn't with an iPhone.

Comment: Without seeing how you're retrieving the asset (either using PHAsset or ALAssetsLibrary) it's really hard to say why exactly the image isn't found.

Comment: Sorry, lastAsset is a PHAsset. I always use PHAsset.

Comment: Can you add that code in there? It's looking like lastAsset maybe isn't working at all.

Comment: This part is in an other file and in Swift

let fetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithMediaType(PHAssetMediaType.Image, options: fetchOptionsImage)

After, I pass the fetchResult array with a segue,
And lastAsset is an object of the fetchResult array.

Comment: Can you NSLog lastAsset to the console? What do you get?

Comment: It's what I obtain : <PHAsset: 0x1701a3100> 196CAF77-3956-4AC5-B4EC-F1A9AA4194CF/L0/001 mediaType=1/0, assetSource=3, (750x1334), creationDate=2015-08-21 14:45:03 +0000, location=0, hidden=0, favorite=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing more code, the best I can come up with is that it's related to one of two things:

Bad paths somewhere after you declare `fileName`; try:

```
fileName = [lastAsset.creationDate.description substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, lastAsset.creationDate.description.length-6)];
NSString* imagePath = [[info objectForKey:@"PHImageFileURLKey"]absoluteString];
[dbRestClient uploadFile:fileName toPath:@"/" withParentRev:nil fromPath:imagePath];
```

Or, if that doesn't work, then it might be related to the immutability of `PHAsset`. Try instead copying to a temp folder:

```
fileName = [lastAsset.creationDate.description substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, lastAsset.creationDate.description.length-6)];
NSString *tmp = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
NSData *data = UIImageJPGRepresentation(result);
[data writeToFile:tmp atomically:YES]; // you might need UIImagePNGRepresentation here as well
[self.dropboxClient uploadFile:fileName toPath:destDir withParentRev:nil fromPath:tmp];
```

Comment: Thank you so much !!

The first solution doesn't works, but the second yes !